# ford fiesta vechie speed sensor

Tags: ford, fiesta

After  a lot of sweat and searing I have finally got the pin out, So I thought the hard bit was over but no. I cannot get the sensor out I have pulled so much that ive only about 5mm of the plastic left, so my Question is im looking to cut it off flush with the gearbox casing then drill a hole in it and screw in a stud extractor (if have some with chunky threads) and try and break the seal as I can spray wd40 in the pin hole, what are your thoughts and tips on this. can see why fords remove the engine to do it
Regards Chris

Comment: What year is it? Manual or automatic?

Comment: It's a 2003 manual

Comment: Sounds like you are doing what I would do.

Comment: Hi right, Update disconnected the battery and put 2 terminals together over night (ended up for 3 days as was in Hospital) well connected all up and run the car for a hour then wife took it around the street for a spin and still nothing, put two handheld code readers and no codes found also run the cars on diagnostics on dash board by holding in the trip counter and turning on the key that came back no codes (faults found). I read online that I may need to be driven a few miles and may come on, Anyway its booked in for MOT this week, So any help I would be greatful 
Regards Chris